# Trouble with perl and UTF-8

Tags: encoding, unicode, perl

If I interpret documentation ci=orrectly, `perl --CSD` is suppose to ensure that input and output, processed or commands, are using UTF-8 encoding.

But if I replace two hyphens `--` with an em-dash — (U+2014), the result is not rendered as an em-dash in UTF-8 locale in MacOS 12.1 (I don't have any other O.S. to try things on).

To avoid the chance of further encoding/rendering issues between upload, server, and client-side rendering, I'm showing a screen shot rather than pasting text:

[image]

If I open the file in an editor that assumes UTF-8 input, it displays the same.  If I use that editor to add in another em-dash, the second one renders correctly, and is definitely encoded differently:

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % od -xc /tmp/demo.txt 
0000000      2049    6177    746e    6120    206e    6d65    642d    7361
           I       w   a   n   t       a   n       e   m   -   d   a   s
0000020      2068    6562    7774    6565    206e    6874    7365    3a65
           h       b   e   t   w   e   e   n       t   h   e   s   e   :
0000040      4a20    656f    a2c3    80c2    94c2    6f54    0a6d    2049
               J   o   e   â  ** 302 200 302 224   T   o   m  \n   I    
0000060      6177    746e    6120    206e    6d65    642d    7361    2068
           w   a   n   t       a   n       e   m   -   d   a   s   h    
0000100      6562    7774    6565    206e    6874    7365    3a65    4a20
           b   e   t   w   e   e   n       t   h   e   s   e   :       J
0000120      656f    80e2    5494    6d6f    0a0a                        
           o   e   —  **  **   T   o   m  \n  \n
```

Is there a bug, or am I doing something wrong?  I need to automate several replacements in many files, and they contain multiple languages, so non-ASCI characters may be on the search side as well as the replacement side.

UPDATE: I do have access to a Debian system, but it's through ssh.  I see the same thing with "perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 65 registered patches …" but since I'm connected remotely, it's still being rendered by my system.

My perl is "perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level" with no mention of patches.

I'm open to another tool instead of perl, if it doesn't require a much bigger script or hours of learning a new language.  There are already several languages I could do this in, but none of them are particularly convenient for this purpose.

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug but it seems that the `O` flag of `-C` cause the "input" (I'm unsure about the exact definition/scope of "input" I'm talking about here) to be treated as Unicode code point for every single byte: http://ix.io/3MDY

Answer (score 0):

The *command line* is not the same thing as standard input and doesn't go through PerlIO – it is a flat string array (`@ARGV` in Perl) which is handled by `-CA` rather than `-CS`. You need `-CSDA` to cover everything.

(Alternatively, call `utf8::decode($_) for @ARGV` near the beginning of your script.)

Comment: Unfortunately, both of those got the same wrong result.  Does @ARGV really matter when using -i (inplace) on a filename?

Comment: Your *regex* is being provided through @ARGV, technically.

Comment: Ah, of course.  My bad.  So wouldn't the decode option need to be invoked before the script starts instead of within the script?  What if I put the script in an actual file with a perl bang-line.  Might that work differently?  (I'm not sure how to do in-place in that case, but I could `< old > temp` and then copy the temp over the old.)

Comment: When the docs say (thing) makes it handle UTF-8 but does the opposite and not using it handles UTF8 correctly, it seems like a bug to me.  But I don't know enough about perl to say that confidently.

Answer (score 0):

From Tom Yan’s comment, it appears that -CSD is actually messing it up somehow.  Leave it out, and usually¹ I get what I want (at least with my locale):

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % echo "Let’s try again for an em-dash" > /tmp/tmp
WGroleau@MBP ~ % cat /tmp/tmp
Let’s try again for an em-dash
WGroleau@MBP ~ % perl -p -i -e 's:em-dash:—:g;' !$
perl -p -i -e 's:em-dash:—:g;' /tmp/tmp
WGroleau@MBP ~ % cat !$
cat /tmp/tmp
Let’s try again for an —
WGroleau@MBP ~ % perl -p -i -e 's:—:--:g;' /tmp/tmp # change it to ASCII
WGroleau@MBP ~ % cat /tmp/tmp
Let’s try again for an --
```

Seems like a bug to me, but I don’t really know.  As I mentioned, there are other non-ASCII substitutions I need to make (testing first, of course).

¹Except that if I try to replace `’` (U+2019) with ASCII `'`, zsh complains of an open quote!  Escape `\'` doesn't help.

Comment: Not using any -C is like "passthrough" mode: it doesn't *try* to handle any encoding at all, neither encoding or decoding, it just handles the input "—" as 3 separate bytes. That's fine in exact match situations, as the bytes are preserved exactly from input to output, but let's say you have "`a—b`" and try to `s/a.//`, this will end up cutting the UTF-8 character in half (the `.` would match one byte rather than one character). That's what -C is for.

Comment: So, in that situation (which fortunately is not currently a problem for me), it looks like it won't work with or without -C.  Still seems to be a bug, in two different versions of perl 5  I have to put the quoting issue in a different question.